# Interpolating xyz coordinates on MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot

```
clear
clc
A = [ --- spherical coordinates (theta, phi, r) [too long] --- ]; % size(A) is 1369 X 3
B = zeros(1369,3);
B(:,1) = A(:,3).*sind(A(:,1)).*cosd(A(:,2));
B(:,2) = A(:,3).*sind(A(:,1)).*sind(A(:,2));
B(:,3) = A(:,3).*cosd(A(:,1));              % converted to cartesian coordinates
raw_x = (B(:, 1))';
raw_y = (B(:, 2));
raw_z = (B(:, 3));
[X, Y] = meshgrid(raw_x, raw_y);            % to use interp2
inter_z = vec2mat((raw_z)', 37);
Z = (inter_z)';
```

Above I am trying to interpolate and plot a set of spherical coordinates. For interpolation, I need to use below command

`interp2(X,Y,Z,xi,yi,'bicubic') % xi and yi will be defined arbitrarily`

However, X, Y and Z need to have the same size to use this command. I have size(X) = size(Y) = 1369 X 1369 and size(Z) = 37 X 37. I could not figure out how I can overcome this confusion correctly. Could you help out?